# Parts of the icon in a JOptionPane is missing on my computer regardless of screenresolution but works on other computers

Tags: java, windows, swing, icons, joptionpane

So, as the title states, the icons that appears in JOptionPanes has missing parts on my computer regardless of screenresolution but works on other computers (the image shows using of lower resolution, 1366x768, but I usually have it on 1920x1080)

The other computer I tried on has 1366x768, and it works just fine!

The question is: Why is this happening (or what might be causing this) and how can I make sure this doesn't happen on other computers?
Since the text I have in for example tables appears tiny I was suspecting it might be because of ClearType is turned on, but it didn't help much to turn it off, and the other computer has that turned on too.

The GUI is set to apply the host OS's Look and Feel, but it has been working before (I develop this software from time to time so for me this just happened suddenly without knowing what might have caused it...)
Both computers I've tried this with runs Windows 8.1

I've searched a lot about this but all I could find was how to put custom icons in a JOptionPane dialog, however that is not what I want.

[image: The icon has missing parts on it's bottom and right edges]

The picture shows the issue with the icon (to the right), while it also shows the screen resolution I tried. Maybe the appearance of the text/icons in the control panel may give a hint of the problem?

Comment: Did you try different Java versions?

Comment: Well, not after the problem occured, I have indeed updated Java since last time I exported an executable, but the very same executable with the new Java version works on the other computer.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the help!
I just found out the problem, which also solved issues I was having with my computers before!

Comment: Share your insights! You can write your own answer and other people might find it useful…

Comment: Just posted the solution! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just did more searching on everything from ClearType to Fonts and just found a solution to my problem!
Apparantly the problem was that my screen had a very high screen resolution so Windows scaled up icons "without telling me".
The slider has the options "smaller" and "larger" (and had also "Medium" when the highest resolution was applied) (Picture #1).

One expect the "smaller" option on the slider to represent scaling of 100% or lower, but when I tick the checkbox for "Let me choose one scaling level for my all displays" (Picture #2), I can see that "Medium (125%)" is equivalent to the "smaller" option on the slider.

Of course this solved my problem with my own java program, but it also solved other problems I had before with icons in Windows UI itself (e.g. non-system icons in the notification-area had bad quality)

---

[image: Showing the slider with the missleading options]

---

Picture #1 Showing the slider with the missleading options

---

[image: Showing the slider with the missleading options]

---

Picture #2 Showing the radio buttons choices with scaling percentage values. Please note: Slider value of "Smaller" in picture one corresponds to "Medium (125%)" in the options of this picture.